# Store Firebase url in an external properties file?

Tags: javascript, git, firebase

I want to put my Firebase url into an external text file and reference that value within my Javascript file.

Currently in my files I have `var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");` but I want this: `var ref = new Firebase("https://" + fbAppName + ".firebaseio.com");`

This is so that I don't have to replace my Firebase app name with `<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>` every time I push changes to my github account. I'd be easier to have the url referenced in an external file and just add that file to my git ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an Angular Constant. See [example](https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099)

```
angular.module('app', []);

.value('movieTitle', 'The Matrix');

.controller('MyController', function (movieTitle) {
  expect(movieTitle).toEqual('The Matrix');
})
```