# Is it a security risk to have the api key and project id of a Firebase app in a public Git repository?

Tags: javascript, git, firebase

I would like to use Firebase as part of a React app that I am building. According to [Add Firebase to your JavaScript Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) we should add the following to a node.js project:

```
// Initialize Firebase
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

1. Is it a security risk to have the `API_KEY` and `PROJECT_ID` in a public Git repository?
2. When using the Firebase CLI a `.firebaserc` is created in JSON format, which contains the `PROJECT_ID`. Is it a security risk to have this in a public  Git repository?

[Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482366/5955911) discusses exposing the API key to the public but doesn't mention Git or the Project ID.

Comment: with only the `API_KEY` and `PROJECT_ID`, can you delete stuff from the firebase database?

Comment: I have edited my question to state why I think this is different.

Comment: It is not a security risk. But common opinion seems to not store this configuration in version control, since each developer should have their own project for developing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358340/should-i-add-the-google-services-json-from-firebase-to-my-repository (for Android), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937175/firebase-should-i-add-googleservice-info-plist-to-gitignore (for iOS). Since the meaning of the configuration data is the same across platforms, I'd follow the same guidance for web. See this for an (old) example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36711729/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My take away is not to store the development configuration (ie any Firebase project that has localhost as an authorised domain) in version control.

Comment: I still think this question adds value. So, it would be nice if someone could remove the duplicate flag :)